# Alternative to caprock.dictionary for 64-bit Windows/IIS 7.5

Tags: windows, asp-classic, vbscript, 64-bit, comobject

My company has a legacy solution, written in Classic ASP/VBScript that uses the caprock.dictionary COM object in the Application scope for storing various recordsets of data.

This works fine on 32-bit Windows/IIS 6.0 but has been rumored to fail on 64-bit Windows.

Aside from migrating this solution to ASP.NET (which we are in the process of doing), is there an alternative to the caprock.dictionary COM object that will do the same thing and work on 64-bit Windows?

Comment: What does caprock.dictionary do that is not provided by the Classic ASP Scripting.Dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You can use motobit. It is much faster than scripting and Caprock ( more than 10 times when  we tested against Caprock)

The issues we noticed in direct conversion are

- Keys are not allowed as blank ( Scripting and Caprock allows that)
- Order is based on the sort order of the key, not in the order you add. Again different from the other 2 Dictionaries.

If these 2 are not an issue then this is the right one for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you'll need to look at porting the concept into some flavor of key-value-pair storage.

Or, maybe, something like this might work ?

http://www.motobit.com/help/asp-dictionary-object/default.htm